# How can I remove a certain character from a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that removes a given character from a string.
The prototype is: removeChar :: Char -> String -> String
I tried to do something like this:

```
removeChar a x =  foldr (++) [] (map (\x -> filter f x) x)
           where 
           f x = elem a x
```

Comment: And then what happened? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

this should be enough, String is nothing but a [Char] so just filter it for that char

```
removeChar::Char->String->String
removeChar a = filter (/=a)
```